# PHP / MySQLi class does not seem to be working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to PHP / MySQLi but think I've made some good progress in this time. However, I am having some issues.

1. In the index.php I have tried to add some conditions if a result is found to display, if nothing found to show a message and then a default message but that is not working but i think its down to my wrong doing on code.
2. I have 4 fields on the form, all need to match in the database table to return result but needs to return * so I can display other data from matched data.

**class.search.php**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

/**
 * Performs a search
 *
 * This class is used to perform search functions in a MySQL database
 *
 * @version 1.0
 * @author James Brandon
 */
class search {
  /**
   * MySQLi connection
   * @access private
   * @var object
   */
  private $mysqli;

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * This sets up the class
   */
  public function __construct() {
    // Connect to our database and store in $mysqli property
    $this->connect();
  }
  /**
   * Database connection
   * 
   * This connects to our database
   */
  private function connect() {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    //$this->mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'reboot_ncddb', 'reboot_ncddb', 'TF69HS-Wm^*F' );
  }

  /**
   * Search routine
   * 
   * Performs a search
   * 
   * @param string $search_term The search term
   * 
   * @return array/boolen $search_results Array of search results or false
   */
  public function search($first_name, $last_name, $postcode, $reg) {
    // Sanitize the search term to prevent injection attacks
    $first_name = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($first_name);
    $last_name = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($last_name);
    $postcode = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($postcode);
    $reg = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($reg);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->mysqli->query("
      SELECT *
      FROM customers
      WHERE first_name = '%{$first_name}%'
      AND last_name = '%{$last_name}%'
      AND postcode = '%{$postcode}%'
      AND reg = '%{$reg}%'
    ");

    // Check results
    if(!$query->num_rows){
      return false;
    }

    // Loop and fetch objects
    while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
      $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // Build our return result
    $search_results = array(
      'count' => $query->num_rows,
      'results' => $rows,
    );

    return $search_results;
  }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
//Check if search data was submitted
if ( isset( $_GET['search_form'] ) ) {
  // Include the search class
  require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/class.search.php' );

  // Instantiate a new instance of the search class
  $search = new search();

  // Store search term into a variable
  $search_first_name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['first_name'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $search_last_name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $search_postcode = htmlspecialchars($_GET['postcode'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $search_reg = htmlspecialchars($_GET['reg'], ENT_QUOTES);

  // Send the search term to our search class and store the result
  $search_results = $search->search($search_first_name, $search_last_name, $search_postcode, $search_reg);
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>search customer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns center">
        <h3>search customer</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-6 columns">

        <form action="" method="get" class="search-form">
          <input type="hidden" name="search_form" id="search_form">

          <div class="row">
            <h4 class="text-center">Search for a customer</h4>
            <div class="small-6 columns">
              <label id="first_name">First Name
                <input name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Joe" value="<?php echo $search_first_name; ?>">
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns">
              <label id="last_name">Last Name
                <input name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Bloggs" value="<?php echo $search_last_name; ?>">
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 columns">
              <label id="postcode">Postcode
                <input name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Ex: E2 8AA" value="<?php echo $search_postcode; ?>">
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns">
              <label id="reg">Registration:
                <input name="reg" type="text" placeholder="CV58 CVZ" value="<?php echo $search_reg; ?>">
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" class="button expanded">Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
      <div class="small-6 columns">
        <?php if($search_results['count']){ ?>
        <div class="results-count">
          <p><?php echo $search_results['count']; ?> results found</p>
        </div>
        <div class="results-table">
          <?php foreach ( $search_results['results'] as $search_result ) : ?>
          <div class="result">
            <p><?php echo $search_result->first_name; ?> <?php echo $search_result->last_name; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $search_result->postcode; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $search_result->reg; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $search_result->ncd; ?></p>
          </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <?php } else if($search_results['count'] == '0') { ?>
          <p>nothign found</p>
        <?php } else { ?>
          <h3>Search for NCD's on the driver database</h3>
          <p>Please use the search form to the left to search and find records for that persons no claims discount on their car insurance record.</p>
        <?php  } ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but it is a good suggestion nonetheless. Always try to make the action explicit in the form. In this case if you omit it there is no problem, but it is just a good habit and improves readability.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: Do not use `htmlspecialchars` for any reason other than escaping content for immediate display in an HTML context. What you're doing here is escaping it prior to searching for things which is going to mess up your search results in a huge way. You won't be able to search for `&` or other "special characters".

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the search method returns an array, you can just do something like this to see if there is a return and decide what to show or not show

```
if (count($search_results) > 0) {
     // process the content
} else {
    // search return content
}
```

Comment: yea just worked that out, works with > 0 and else but not with not found so trying to debug to work out

Comment: I need to i guess have 3 conditions, if found to do condition, if not found to do condition and then a default...

Comment: Your search method returns false if there are no results. So, you could add something to what @Nolly suggested. First ask if the result if of type array. If it is not, there were no results and you may say this to the user. If it is, do what Nolly said.